# How to Join a string with variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am passing mysql query resultset into a javascript variable and then that is variable is concatenated with the URL. 
But during the concatenation it is giving some issue because the resultset has a value "+" in that.
So how can i concatenate my string with variable other than using + in javascript?
Is there any other way?

```
var ser = "B+A+C+";
var url = "../include/helper.php?flag=search&&query="+ser;
```

Comment: The issue lies not with the code you provided. What is your serverside code?

Comment: Having `+` in a string is absolutely no barrier to concatenating it. I'm guessing the issue is about what a + means in a URL, but its really unclear from your question.

Comment: In the URL + is for concatenating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string concatenation in JS is being done just fine. The actual problem is with the PHP, which by default treats a `+` in a URL parameter to mean a space, not a literal + sign. If you replace the + in your string with `%2B`, the hex code for a + sign, it should work:

```
var ser = "B%2BA%2BC%2B";
var url = "../include/helper.php?flag=search&&query="+ser;
```

You could also do this automatically with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (thanks Jauco):

```
var ser = encodeURIComponent("B+A+C+B");
var url = "../include/helper.php?flag=search&&query="+ser;
```

Comment: You probably want to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of manually replacing the plus-es. It will escape any other non url safe characters as well.

Comment: It is the RIGHT answer...   Thanx Scimonster and Jauco